# appendChild give an error, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I found a lot of questions here about this problem, but i still can't figure out how to fix it in my case.
Now i created a new html file and have there only this code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
     var obj = new Object;
         document.getElementById("a").appendChild(obj);
    };
</script>
```

I tryed to place it in different places, with and without "onload" function, using getElementById or just document.body, but i get an error:
"Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist."

Thank you, guys.

Comment: You can only pass DOM elements to `appendChild()`, and `obj` is not a DOM element.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. But can u give me an advice how to create a DOM element from obj?

Comment: See Gal V's answer: you cannot create a DOM element from a simple object, you will have to pass an element name to `createElement()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appendChild` will work only with a DOM element.
try:

```
var obj = document.createElement('div');
```

instead of:

```
var obj = new Object;
```

(btw, need to use `new Object()` and not `new Object`)

hope that helped.

Comment: I like how you not just gave the right answer but also corrected the second mistake new object (). +1